# Transaction fee payer required error when listing a token on Auction House

Tags: solana, metaplex

I'm trying to list a token on Auction House (AH) using Metaplex JS SDK, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

First I created the AH

```js
const { auctionHouse } = await metaplex
        .auctions()
        .createAuctionHouse({
          auctioneerAuthority: systemKeypair.publicKey,
          authority: systemKeypair,
          feeWithdrawalDestination: systemKeypair.publicKey,
          payer: systemKeypair,
          sellerFeeBasisPoints: 300,
          treasuryWithdrawalDestinationOwner: systemKeypair.publicKey,
          requiresSignOff: true,
          canChangeSalePrice: true,
          treasuryMint: WRAPPED_SOL_MINT,
          auctioneerScopes: [
            AuthorityScope.Buy,
            AuthorityScope.Cancel,
            AuthorityScope.Deposit,
            AuthorityScope.ExecuteSale,
            AuthorityScope.PublicBuy,
            AuthorityScope.Sell,
            AuthorityScope.Withdraw,
          ],
        })
        .run()
```

This is what `metaplex.auctions().findAuctionHouseByCreatorAndMint` returns:

```json
{
  "address": "DSPhjY5tzm9xpeLHkAVZc1JxR2sn23ny5CvwhYXtGZ7d",
  "creatorAddress": "8YaerWbLjVptW8GmvHC8QVVTfKRBqd9r5XN1Thvam63o",
  "authorityAddress": "8YaerWbLjVptW8GmvHC8QVVTfKRBqd9r5XN1Thvam63o",
  "treasuryMint": {
    "model": "mint",
    "address": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
    "mintAuthorityAddress": null,
    "freezeAuthorityAddress": null,
    "decimals": 9,
    "supply": {
      "basisPoints": "00",
      "currency": {
        "symbol": "SOL",
        "decimals": 9,
        "namespace": "spl-token"
      }
    },
    "isWrappedSol": true,
    "currency": {
      "symbol": "SOL",
      "decimals": 9,
      "namespace": "spl-token"
    }
  },
  "feeAccountAddress": "4CpCLtfEyRpHR5kJxfqCEmYx3P7HmqLmpFWwEQntSyc7",
  "treasuryAccountAddress": "GWJBrb67aEt4hrHY6CEM16kpAXboJp5pV3iCDicoJXkS",
  "feeWithdrawalDestinationAddress": "8YaerWbLjVptW8GmvHC8QVVTfKRBqd9r5XN1Thvam63o",
  "treasuryWithdrawalDestinationAddress": "8YaerWbLjVptW8GmvHC8QVVTfKRBqd9r5XN1Thvam63o",
  "sellerFeeBasisPoints": 300,
  "requiresSignOff": true,
  "canChangeSalePrice": true,
  "isNative": true,
  "hasAuctioneer": true,
  "auctioneer": {
    "address": "8nMN6zC957r6rrh4w8EjDHFXwW7KbeKrXUdUva224MpV",
    "authority": "8YaerWbLjVptW8GmvHC8QVVTfKRBqd9r5XN1Thvam63o",
    "scopes": []
  }
}
```

and finally the listing

```js
const response = await metaplex
    .auctions()
    .for(
      auctionHouse,
      systemKeypair
    )
    .list({
      authority: systemKeypair,
      bookkeeper: systemKeypair,
      mintAccount: new PublicKey(mintAddress),
      seller: userKeypair,
      price: sol(price),
    })
    .run()
```

but the `list` call always throws the error `Transaction fee payer required`.

I also think now the `auctioneerAuthority` isn't necessary for my use case, but I couldn't remove it (set as undefined) using the `metaplex.auctions().updateAuctionHouse` function.

Answer (score 0):

As `requiresSignOff` is set to `true`, the Auction House uses a `Fee Payer account` to pay the fees on chain for sales execution, transfers and account creation.

You can read more about it here: https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/auction-house/cli#fee-account

You can find the fee payer account using the `show` command, and simply have to airdrop required SOL into the account.

Comment: I sent an airdrop to all addresses used by AH and, unfortunately, it didn't work. I also had added more details about the AH I'm using on devnet.